# Resizing Android soft keyboard in Portrait mode

Tags: android, resize, android-softkeyboard

Is it possible to resize the Android soft keyboard in portrait mode? The keyboard is taking up about half my screen. I would like to decrease the height of the keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.

The only thing that comes to mind is that you can disable suggestions (if they are enabled). For this you can use `inputType="textNoSuggestions"` attribute in layout.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your info. I was hoping I could easily adjust the height of the keyboard.